# Mail issues with PHP hiding warnings for failed SMTP errors

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am using php 5 and i am try to send an email my email address is also correct but email is not sent by mail function and mail function not showing any warning i have enable error reporting to maximum see below my code and please tell what is i am missing

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$a = mail('test.vipan@gmail.com','test','test');

if($a){
    echo 'sent mail';
}else echo 'Failed to send mail';
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: is there any mail relay had been config ?

Comment: no nothing has been configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From php.net:

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

I'd take a long hard look at my logs.

Comment: and when it shows errors like Warning: mail(): Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i' in /home/magento/www/testmail.php on line 5

Comment: Can your web server run the `sendmail` command?

This can help on selinux:
`semanage boolean -m --on httpd_can_sendmail`